# My React modal component for a submit and edit form won't close?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, href

I have a React project that has a modal component in it. There is a button to open the modal which works fine but the other button which is meant to close the modal does not work. I tried to remove the onClick function but that did not make any difference. Below is the code:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import ContactContext from "../../context/contact/contactContext";

// CrUd - Create and Update contact
const ContactForm = () => {
  const contactContext = useContext(ContactContext);
  const { createContact, clearCurrentContact, updateContact, current } =
    contactContext;
  // add contact details of current contact if edit button is clicked
  useEffect(() => {
    current
      ? setContact(current)
      : setContact({
          name: "",
          email: "",
          phone: "",
          type: "personal",
        });
  }, [contactContext, current]);

  // default values of the contact form
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    type: "personal",
  });
  const { name, email, phone, type } = contact;

  // add values to temporary object
  const onChange = change =>
    setContact({ ...contact, [change.target.name]: change.target.value });

  // if submit button is clicked
  const onSubmit = submit => {
    submit.preventDefault();
    // choose weather to create or update a contact
    !current ? createContact(contact) : updateContact(contact);
    // revert form to default values
    clearContactForm();
  };

  // if clear button is clicked
  const clearContactForm = () => {
    if (current) clearCurrentContact();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <a href="#contact-form">
        <button className="create-contact-button">+</button>
      </a>

      <form className="contact-form" id="contact-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <h2>{current ? "Update contact" : "Create contact"}</h2>
        {/* input fields */}
        <input
          className="input-field"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          placeholder="Name"
          required
        />
        <input
          className="input-field"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={onChange}
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <input
          className="input-field"
          minLength="8"
          maxLength="8"
          type="phone"
          name="phone"
          value={phone}
          onChange={onChange}
          placeholder="Phone"
        />
        {/* personal or professional check box */}
        <div>
          <h3>Contact type</h3>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="type"
            value="personal"
            checked={type === "personal"}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          &nbsp; Personal &nbsp;
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="type"
            value="professional"
            checked={type === "professional"}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
          &nbsp; Professional
        </div>
        {/* submit and clear button */}
        <div>
          <a href="#!">
            <input
              className="button button-submit"
              type="submit"
              value={current ? "Update contact" : "Create contact"}
            />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#!">
            <button
              className="button button-form-clear"
              onClick={clearContactForm}
            >
              Cancel
            </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

```css
:root {
    --main-color: #00308f;
    --secondary-color: #7cb9e8;
    --dark-color: #444;
    --light-color: #fafafa;
}
body {
    font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    color: var(--dark-color);
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 70px 0 0;
    padding: 1em;
}
h2,
h3 {
    color: var(--main-color);
}
.button {
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 1.25em;
    font-weight: 700;
    min-width: 80px;
}
.create-contact-button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0.75em;
    right: 0.75em;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    border: 0.1em solid var(--light-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    color: var(--light-color);
    opacity: 90%;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 3em;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.1em var(--dark-color);
}
.create-contact-button:hover {
    background-color: var(--light-color);
    color: var(--main-color);
    border: 0.1em solid var(--main-color);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.5em var(--dark-color);
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.contact-form {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    display: grid;
    align-self: center;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.contact-form:target {
    visibility: visible;
}
.button-submit {
    margin: 1.25em 0 0;
    padding: 0.6em 1.25em;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--main-color),var(--secondary-color),var(--secondary-color),var(--secondary-color),var(--main-color));
    border: solid 1.5px var(--main-color);
    color: var(--main-color);
}
.button-submit:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,var(--secondary-color),var(--main-color),var(--main-color),var(--main-color),var(--secondary-color));
    border: solid 1.5px var(--secondary-color);
    color: var(--light-color);
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.button-form-clear {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    border: solid 1.5px #a9a9a9;
    color: var(--dark-color);
    margin: 1.25em 0;
    padding: 0.6em 1.25em;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1.5px var(--main-color);
}
.button-form-clear:hover {
    background-color: #a9a9a9;
    border: solid 1.5px #d3d3d3;
    color: var(--light-color);
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.input-field {
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    border: solid 1px var(--secondary-color);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    height: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (max-width:614px) {
    body {
        margin-top: 130px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Why isn't the modal closing?

Comment: What does `clearCurrentContact` do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `button`, `input` must not appear as a descendant of the `a` element, check here https://validator.w3.org/. You must remove `button`, `input` from `a`, in this case click on `a` not work.
Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-kalam-h3idc, all code where `ContactContext` is used, commented out. Also used `useRef` on `form`, to do submitting throught `dispatchEvent`